Receiving double push notification in my flutter app with firebase
I am receiving push notifications in my flutter app and using firebase. When sending through firebase I receive it only once and when sending through backend server I receive it twice.
I am using flutter local notifications to display the notifications in Android.
As stated in documentation - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#handling-notifications-whilst-the-app-is-in-the-foreground
I have enabled presentation options as follows
 const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
    );

Future<void> enableIOSNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

Please let me know if I have to edit code in AppDelegate.swift to solve this issue or any other important configuration which I am missing.

in the body send empty map for notification value

Hi @MunsifAli so I need to pass empty map for notification value from backend server ?

checkout the answer if it is working for you.

Send this in the body from server
{
    "to":"_some_fcm_token_",
    "notification": {},//remove this line
    "type": "post_like",
    "data": {
        "model":{"id":"dsaflkdskfklgdkgjdksakdk"},
        "body": "this is subtitle",
        "title": "this is title",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },
    "priority": "normal"
}

send without notifiction key-value
